# Loop Through Multi-Level Dynamic Menus in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, loops, asp.net-mvc-4

i am trying to loop through multilevel dynamic menus. I have been succeeded to do this manually i.e everytime if want to display the child `Menus` of it's parent, I have to loop manually. **I would like to know the best way or an alternative of looping multi-level through these dynamic menus**
Here is what i have done so far;

```
@{ var menusList = ViewBag.Menus as IEnumerable<ParentMenuViewModel>; }
@foreach (var parentMenu in menusList.Where(p => p.ParentId == 0))
{
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h1>@parentMenu.Name</h1>
            @if (menusList.Count(p => p.ParentId == parentMenu.MenuId) > 0)
            {
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var childMenu in menusList.Where(p => p.ParentId == parentMenu.MenuId))
                    {
                        <h2>@childMenu.Name</h2>
                        if (menusList.Count(p => p.ParentId == childMenu.MenuId) > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var subChild in menusList.Where(p => p.ParentId == childMenu.MenuId))
                            {
                                <h3>@subChild.Name</h3>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </ul>
            }
        </li>
    </ul>

}
```

**UPDATE:** The output looks like this;

```
HOME
 SUB MENU1
  SUB SUB MENU1
  SUB SUB MENU2
```

However, i have in my database something like this;

```
HOME
 SUB MENU1
  SUB SUB MENU1
  SUB SUB MENU2
    Sub SUB SUB MENU1
    Sub SUB SUB MENU2
```

Here is my model;
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a partialview and then do a recursive loop. In order to do that you'd first need to change your Model a bit:

**ViewModel**

```
// The ViewModel is now a hirearchical model, where each item has a list of children.
public class MenuViewModel
{
    int MenuId {get; set;}
    string Name {get; set;}
    //other properties
    ** snip ** 
    List<MenuViewModel> Children {get; set;}
}
```

**Controller**

Transform model into the hierarchical ViewModel:

```
public ActionResult Menus(){
    List<Menu> menusource; // get your menus here
    ViewBag.Menus = CreateVM(0, menusource);  // transform it into the ViewModel
    return View();
}

public IEnumerable<MenuViewModel> CreateVM(int parentid, List<Menu> source)
{
    return from men in source
           where men.ParentId = parentid
           select new MenuViewModel(){
                      MenuId = men.MenuId, 
                      Name = men.Name
                      // other properties
                      Children = CreateVM(men.MenuId, source)
                  };
}
```

**View**

```
@{ 
    var menusList = ViewBag.Menus as IEnumerable<MenuViewModel>; 
    Html.RenderPartial("MenuPartial", menuslist);
}
```

**MenuPartial**

```
@model IEnumerable<MenuViewModel>

@foreach (var menuitem in model)
{
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h1>@menuitem.Name</h1>
            @{
                Html.RenderPartial("MenuPartial", menuitem.Children);
            }
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

The only thing you will be missing here with regards to your original code is that you don't have different Hx-tags, but you could find a way around that by creating another viewmodel and passing it the level you are currently at.

Note: I typed up all this code in the SO-editor, so there may be some small syntax errors.

Comment: can you make it asycronous( your code). i tried but didn't succed. Using async and await keywords

Comment: partially right. How you are rendering in view is not seems correct